# Replace Lambdas with method reference.

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference

Please help me to understand how to replace lambdas with method reference for the method below.

```
    public List<Person> sortByStartDate_ASC(LinkedHashSet<Person> personList) {

        List<Person> pList = new ArrayList<Person>(personList);

        Collections.sort(pList, (Person person1, Person person2) -> person1
            .getStartDate().compareTo(person2.getStartDate()));
        return pList;
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The equivalent method reference would be `comparing(Person::getStartDate)` - note that in your specific case you could sort the stream directly. Also there is no point restricting your method to only accept `LinkedHashSet`s - any collection would do:

```
public List<Person> sortByStartDate_ASC(Collection<Person> personList) {
  return personList.stream()
                   .sorted(comparing(Person::getStartDate))
                   .collect(toList());
}
```

Note required static imports:

```
import static java.util.Comparator.comparing;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Comparator.comparing`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) helper method:

```
Collections.sort(pList, Comparator.comparing(Person::getStartDate));
```